# How can I change the IP and gateway addresses permanently?

Tags: linux, command-line, ip

I recently installed Linux Ubuntu 14.04 to my computer. To enable internet connection I needed to change my IP and Gateway address.
I did the following as a root user

```
# ifconfig eth0 "my ip address here" netmask 255.255.255.0 up
# route add default gw " gw address here"
```

It works fine for a couple of minutes but then goes back to the previous settings every time.
So, How can I change the IP and the gw addresses permanently?

Comment: Are you using network-manager?  You probably are if you haven't installed another connection manager.

Comment: I am not using anything similar to that since I couldnt connect to the Internet. Just from command line.

Comment: Yes, but if you are in the default GUI (Unity), network-manager will automatically be started.  It looks like a pair of arrows, one up, one down, in the system tray.

Comment: If network-manager is running, it start a dhcp client (probably `dhclient`); that will attempt to autoconfigure the network, and that's probably why your settings get overwritten.

Comment: So should I disable network-manager ??

Comment: If you don't want it running, yes.  You can set a static ip with it though.  When I click on it and choose "Edit Connections", there's an option for "manual" under "IPv4 Settings".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As stated by jpkotta, network-manager is likely the culprit.

You can see its status by running `ps -aux | grep network-manager | grep <username>`. If you get a result, it is running, otherwise it isn't.

It will keep overwriting any changes you make with ifconfig as long as it is running.

Kill network-manager by running `sudo service network-manager stop`. 

You can bring it back up any time with `sudo service network-manager start`.

Once it is disabled, use ifconfig to set your static, OR edit your `/etc/network/interfaces` file to include something like:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.2
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.1.0
broadcast 192.168.1.255
gateway 192.168.1.1
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

Finally, run `ifup -a` to bring up the interfaces you have in your `/etc/network/interfaces` file.

All of this can be avoided though, if you'd rather not mess around with killing network manager. Just click on its icon in the taskbar and click 'edit connections'.

Answer (score 1):

Commands which you have to fire are:

1. Check your NIC `ifconfig`
2. Choose one and set it with ip which you want to give: `ifconfig enp0s8 192.168.1.34`
3. go to `cd /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/`
4. edit NIC file:

vim ifcfg-enp0s8

```
write ---------
```

'IPADDR' = 192.168.1.34
'NETMASK'= 255.255.255.0
'ONBOOT' = yes
'BOOTPROTO'= 'static'

```
5. done
```

Comment: There is already a more valid, complete, and well formatted answer.